# Displaying something else when number in array equals zero

Tags: php, mysql

I managed to display the data from a MySQL Database, but I have run into a problem. 
What I want to achieve is when the value of **price** equals **0** it should display **Free** instead of just 0. 
 
I tried to find a solution online but maybe I was searching wrong, because I am rather new to PHP.

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $amount  = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);
    echo '
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['event'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['price'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['address'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['info'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['contact'].'</td>
            </tr>';
}?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. It looks like you are testing for `0` in the ternary and assigning a value or nothing to `$amount`

```
$amount = ($row['amount'] == 0) ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);
```

You could change this around to (assuming the `amount` data type is a number and not a string):

```
$amount = ($row['amount']) ? '$'.number_format($row['amount']) : 'Free';
```

If `amount` is a string in the DB, you may need to test for `"0"` like you had almost:

```
$amount = ($row['amount'] !== "0") ? '$'.number_format($row['amount']) : 'Free';
```

Then you have the next issue - you never used `$amount` in your code :]

The full change (based on your code sample):

```
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        // Assign either 'Free' or a formatted value to '$amount'
        $amount = ($row['amount']) ? '$'.number_format($row['amount']) : 'Free';
        // And be sure to use $amount here
        echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['event'].'</td>
            <td>'.$amount.'</td>
            <td>'.$row['adress'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['info'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['contact'].'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
?>
```

NOTE: You also have a spelling error in `$row['adress']`, unless the error is in the DB table as well, it should be `$row['address']`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this?

`echo ($row['price'] == 0) ? 'free' : $row['price'];`

Answer (score 0):

You've got some broken formatting in that code, but you've got the right idea.  Specifically, this line:

`$amount  = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);`

Will do exactly what you want.  Simply change it as follows:

`$amount  = $row['amount'] == 0 ? 'Free' : number_format($row['amount']);`

Then `echo $amount;` where you want the amount to display the word "Free" if the amount is zero.  You can do that for the price specifically, if you like.

e.g.

`echo '\t<td>', $row['price'] == 0 ? 'Free' : number_format($row['amount']), '</td>';`